# BeginXXX and threadpool

Tags: c#

I'm writing a TCP Server in C# and I'm using the BeginXXX and EndXXX methods for async communication. If I understand correctly, when I use BeginXXX the request will be handled on in the threadpool (when the request is ready) while the main thread keeps accepting new connections.

The question is what happens if I perform a blocking action in one of these AsyncCallbacks? Will it be better to run a blocking operation as a task? Tasks use the threadpool as well don't they?

The use case is the following:

The main thread set ups a listening socket which accepts connections using BeginAccept, and starts listening on those connections using BeginReceive. When a full message has been received, a function is called depending on what that message was, in 80% of all cases, those functions will start a database query/insertion/update.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The question is what happens if I perform a blocking action in one of these AsyncCallbacks? Will it be better to run a blocking operation as a task?

If you do that too often or for too long then the ThreadPool will grow. Possible to the point where it will crash your App.

So try to avoid blocking as much as possible. But a little bit of it should be acceptable. Keep in mind that the ThreadPool will grow with 1 new thread per 500 ms. So make sure and verify that it will level out on some reasonable number of threads.

A blunt instrument could be to cap the MaxThreads of the pool.

> Tasks use the threadpool as well don't they?

Yes, so your options are limited.

Comment: hmm ok. In this case the blocking operation will be a database query, but I guess that will in most cases be below 500ms :)

Comment: Why don't you query the db asynchronously?

Comment: But only when needed. The goal is to use threads when you actually have something to do with it rather than keeping it while waiting for other things to happen such as getting the results from a database.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you use SocketAsyncEventArgs which is introduced in .net 4.5

Here's some reading material you can start with

[click me](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/83102/C-SocketAsyncEventArgs-High-Performance-Socket-Cod)

Comment: in which part of your code you need to query database? Is it possible to illustrate the logic please?

Comment: Added the use case to the question. Upvoted for good reading material. Though I will probably use BeginXXX methods until they become the bottleneck, before switching to SocketAsyncEventArgs, becouse the BeginXXX methods are way simpler to implement.